# Bash Virtualbox custom script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am pretty new to bash scripting but I typed this up using Ubuntu via Terminal using the nano editor but i keep getting errors at the password verify part.

Code below:

```
echo Welcome
goto logon
logon()
{
echo Please enter password to use script...
read password
if $pass == "password"; then
goto root
else
goto exit
}

root()
{
echo Please enter password to grant access to root...
sudo -i
goto vbox
}

vbox()
{
echo Starting vbox ...
mount -t vboxsf Tarun /home/user/Tarun
if [ -f /home/user/Tarun/check.chk
then
echo  Folder successfully attached!
cd /home/user/Tarun
ls -l
else
echo Failed! Check vbox config...
goto exit
}

exit()
{
exit
fi
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What is "goto"?  If that is the same as "call", then it must be some weird alias or function in your environment.  Anyway, you cannot invoke a function before you've defined it.  And I'd lose that "goto" thingy.  It is not part of bash.

Comment: the `if` statement has missing close square bracket. And avoid using metacharacters like `!` in a string.

Comment: Wow, there are more problems with this script than I think I can count. Can you describe briefly what it is you want to achieve?

Some general pointers:
- Calling a function does not require `goto`, and will return after the function ends. Goto is generally a bad idea.
- `sudo` always needs to know what command to execute, perhaps you were looking for `su`